# Disk issues (JavaScript error in the main process)

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, ssd, fsck

I seem to be having ocassional SSD (Patriot Blaze) I/O Errors evne though all the tests show disk to be healthy, clean and operational, at only 7 months of age.

**UPDATE**: A third instance of disk freezing was completely frozen with CAPSLOCK light blinking. Hard shut down and reboot solves the problem.

Booting 16.04 LTS sometimes fails, displaying the **"there's no bootable device" error**, and restart or shutdown/power on solves the problem, and I boot into Ubuntu fine.

At other times, when using Ubuntu the system stops working whereas I can move the mouse but cannot open anything. **I also get the following error**:

```
JavaScript error in the main process    

Error: EIO: i/o error, read
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:651:19)
    at process.binding.internalModuleReadFile
    (ELECTRON_ASAR.js: 538:10)
    at readPackage (module.js:88:14)
    at tryPackage (module.js:105:13)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:167:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
```

For example, the last time this happened I rebooted and got the i**nfrarm error** which said I should run fsck of my SSD, so I did and it fixed some errors, and now it works fine. But again, it will happen again.

Now, the **self-test analysis (> Disks)** reveals no problems (DISK OK). It's an 128 GB SSD in operation for 7 months, and the Lenovo z51-70 is 8 months old as well.

Smartmontools testing reveals no problems,smartctl -t short -a /dev/sda:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   30) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2548
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1017
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       20
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       53018675
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       40
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0023   070   070   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       30
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
218 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2791558

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2548         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2537         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1098         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1098         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       251         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Why this all of a sudden? Could the SSD be failing without the testing reporting so?

Cheers.

Comment: Yes, in principle it could, but it is unlikely. What for me it's more probable, it might be a cable/connection problem. Try to replace the cable, clean the contacts really carefully, maybe change the port it is attached to.

Comment: Yeah, seems to be the case. However, I must take it to my dealer's since warranty is void if I remove the casing. One of those laptop without maintanance. Sucks.